# Getting Consecutive Pairs from a List

Tags: java, collections, refactoring, guava, apache-commons

I'm refactoring some code and a piece of it looks like this -

```
    public void addElementPairsToConfig(final Config config, final Element element1, final Element element2, final Element...elements) throws Exception {  
        config.addDependency(element1, element2);
        Element currentElement = element2;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        config.addDependency(currentElement, elements[i]);
        currentElement = elements[i];
        }   
    }
```

Here's how I think it should actually look -

```
    public void addElementPairsToConfig(final Config config, final Element...elements) throws Exception {        
        for (Pair<Element, Element> pair : elements.getNextPair()) {
        config.addDependency(pair.getFirst(), pair.getLast());
        }   
    }
```

I know that `Apache Commons` has a `Pair` class, I'll use that but couldn't find a List util method that does this, is there one that exists. I don't mind writing one myself but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel and use something from `Apache Commons` or `Guava` if it exists there.

In the ruby world I'd use something like [slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your change for the method signature is excellent. However, your idea for the method implementation is over-design. I recommend to keep it simple:

```
public void addElementPairsToConfig(final Config config, final Element...elements) throws Exception {        
    for (int i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
        config.addDependency(elements[i-1], elements[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this is so much more elegant!
I don't like iterating with `i` but I think that in this case it's the best approach.